# Why my tasks does not run in parallel in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm learning hadoop, and I'm doing some experiment on a project that could go in production as a big data project. At the moment anyway I'm just doing some test with a small amount data. The scenario is as follow there is a bounch of json files that I load in pig as below:

```
a = load 's3n://mybucket/user_*.json' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map []);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE flatten(json#'user') as (m:map[]) ;
```

let's say file are small, they contain just one object, but there is a bounch of them. I'm supposing the FOREACH would work in parallel opening more file at once, am I wrong? 
Programs take a while to run about 10 seconds on an amazon c3.xlarge istance, and there is about 400 files. I'm sure if I do a program in C# it will take fraction of second to run, where am I wrong?

Comment: C# can read hundreds from files from s3 in a fraction of a second? I'm not sure about that

Comment: In any case, if you want parallel processing, use Spark, not Pig

Comment: @cricket_007 so s3 is the bottleneck? but anyway should I see more than one mapper running?

Comment: I would assume the network is one of the bottlenecks, yes. Additionally, you appear to be loading all the files into a single Pig record. If these filesizes do not add to more than a single HDFS block (depends on the settings, but 64MB default), you should only be getting one mapper

Comment: @cricket_007 you really want to say that pig is not designed to run parallel task?

Comment: Pig creates a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) of the operations. You have a very linear operation (load and transform). Which part of this do you expect to be parallel? The s3 download? The foreach?

Comment: @cricket_007 the FOREACH yield a map-reduce task, so yes, the foreach part I expect to parallelize

Comment: Like I said, if you have many small files that, in total, do not add to more than one HDFS block, you only have one mapper

Comment: @cricket_007 since files are on s3, why is hdfs block size important?

Comment: I believe your files are read from s3 into local temp, then worked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig runs task as parallel, there is some amount of time pig spends initially  becuase it runs as mapreduce and optimizes the whole script, so operating on small data set will be slower in pig. It should be used for big dataset. To increase the number of parallel task in pig for small data, you can used the PARALLEL command in the FOREACH line, else you can overall increase the number of reducer by set default_parallel n, to set the parallelism to n. 
The last case can be that pig is running all task as mapper, and the number of mapper is too small as your file size is small, you have to change some yarn configuration to increase the number of mappers.